# cant access localhost:8080 tomcat default page

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, localhost

I installed tomcat v6.0 to my computer and I am trying to reach a web page. I added a project for SVN to eclipse. When I try to run it as server, it gives the following page:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /first/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /first/

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
```

Also on console these are logged:

```
02.Tem.2013 16:36:45 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in        production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program     Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools;C:\Users\HasanFerit\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
02.Tem.2013 16:36:45 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property    'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:first' did not find a matching property.
02.Tem.2013 16:36:45 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
02.Tem.2013 16:36:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 586 ms
02.Tem.2013 16:36:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
02.Tem.2013 16:36:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
02.Tem.2013 16:36:46 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
02.Tem.2013 16:36:46 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
02.Tem.2013 16:36:46 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/14  config=null
02.Tem.2013 16:36:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 480 ms
```

Then I tried to open localhost:8080, I doesnt work too... It opens the same page. I doesnt work. What can cause this problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

When you run Tomcat from Eclipse, it won't show you the default page at `localhost:8080/`.  Run it outside of Eclipse to see that page.

As for your project, check the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file to see what default pages are available in the `welcome-file-list`.  Tomcat checks that list to try to resolve requests to the web app root.

Comment: I tried it outside when the tomcat server is closed localhost:8080 doesnt open anything, when I run the server it gives the error above..

Comment: By "the tomcat server is closed", do you mean that Eclipse is closed, or that the Tomcat server is not running?

Comment: Tomcat server is not running. Also what sould be inside welcome-file-list?

Comment: You'll need to have the Tomcat server running, just not launched from Eclipse.  The `welcome-file-list` usually has at least one HTML or JSP page in your application root.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not change anything in your Tomcat `conf/server.xml`, a properly running Tomcat server should show you a Tomcat page on http://localhost:8080 with the message "If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!".

Make sure you set the following environment variables correctly `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME`, and `CATALINA_HOME`. [Instructions for Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/), [Instructions for Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

If you needed to add / change one of those, make sure the changes are applied (e.g. on Windows you can log off and login again, on Mac / Unix you can run `source ~/.bash_profile` from the Terminal).

Now open a terminal (`Terminal` on Mac, `cmd.exe` on Windows) and start Tomcat by running:

- Windows: `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat`
- Mac: `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`

In the terminal / console, you should see something like:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   ...
Using CATALINA_HOME:   ...
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: ...
Using JRE_HOME:        ...
Using CLASSPATH:       ...
```

Now, try opening http://localhost:8080 in a browser. It should show you the Tomcat page as described above.